# Реализация метода setValueAt (TableModel)

Tags: jtable, java, swing

Есть необходимость реализовать модель таблицы (DefaultTableModel не устраивает). Поэтому наследую **AbstractTableModel**. Тут возникает проблема: **не получается редактировать ячейки**. Метод isCellEditable() я определил, теперь значения редактируются, **но не сохраняются в таблице** (например при смене фокуса на другую ячейка). Насколько я понимаю, мне нужно реализовать метод setValueAt(). Но как это метод будет узнавать, какая ячейка редактируется, и какое значение в ней должно остаться? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Тоже столкнулся с этой проблемой, спустя время нашел решения, к примеру, если у вас **getValueAt** выглядит как-то так:

```
private List<Week> weekN;
//...
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
    {
        Week wk=weekN.get(rowIndex);
        switch(columnIndex)
        {
            case 0: return wk.day;
            case 1: return wk.time;
            case 2: return wk.less;
            case 3: return wk.aud;
            case 4: return wk.lect;
            case 5: return wk.type;
        }
        return "";
    }
//...
```

то, **setValueAt** будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
public void setValueAt(Object value, int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
{
    Week wk=weekN.get(rowIndex);

    switch(columnIndex)
    {
        case 0: wk.day=(String)value; break;
        case 1: wk.time=(String)value; break;
        case 2: wk.less=(String)value; break;
        case 3: wk.aud=(String)value; break;
        case 4: wk.lect=(String)value; break;
        case 5: wk.type=(String)value; break;
    }

    //fireTableCellUpdate(rowIndex,columnIndex);
}
```

P.S. Надеюсь, это кому-нибудь еще пригодится.